# transform dataframe columns and keep orginals

Tags: pandas

If I have a dataframe with 3 columns A, B ,C

Is it possible to get the rank for example of these columns but keeping the original.

so df

```
A   B   C
3   4   2
1   2   3

df.add_suffix('_Rank')=df.rank(axis=1)


A   B   C  A_Rank   B_Rank    C_Rank
3   4   2    2       3           1
1   2   3    1        2          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) in right side:

```
df = df.join(df.rank(axis=1).add_suffix('_Rank'))
```

Or add `_Rank` to columns names for new columns:

```
df[df.columns + '_Rank'] = df.rank(axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  A_Rank  B_Rank  C_Rank
0  3  4  2     2.0     3.0     1.0
1  1  2  3     1.0     2.0     3.0
```